# Why is Indian movie industry called as Bollywood?

Tags: indian-cinema

Why does Indian movie industry use a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) as a name?

For instance, I never heard of "[Hong Kong-wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_of_Hong_Kong)".

Comment: Bollywood is a pun of Hollywood, but "Hong Kong-wood" is not.

Comment: Because Mumbai was Bombay, and Indian film industry wanted to name it something like "Hollywood", so they named it Bollywood, the same way how Tamil movies become Tollywood.

Comment: You should have a look at this list - [List of Hollywood inspired nick names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hollywood-inspired_nicknames).

Comment: @DeepakKamat Tollywood is the name of Telugu film industry. Please do some research before commenting.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I got confused between Telugu and Tamil.

Comment: Bollywood is not the indian movie industy, it is one of them.....please remember that

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood

> The name "Bollywood" is a portmanteau derived from Bombay (the former name for Mumbai) and Hollywood (in California), the center of the American film industry.[14]

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Bollywood

> Origin and Etymology of bollywood
>
> Bombay (Mumbai), traditional center of the Indian film industry + Hollywood
>
> First Known Use: 1969

Answer (score 0):

The term *Bollywood* was actually second in line after *Tollywood*, which is used to refer to West Bengal movies and is also a portmanteau (Tollygunge, a city in Calcutta, and Hollywood combined).

Now, the term "Tollywood", according to Wikipedia, dates back to the 1930s, back when India was still under the British rule. During this age, motion pictures first started to emerge in India. The term "tollywood" was mostly informal, only spoken in gossip. Overtime, it became an official, universally accepted term, especially after it got popularized by the *Junior Statesman* youth magazine.

After "Tollywood" became official, terms like "Bollywood", "Dhallywood", "Pollywood", etc. began to emerge. The "-ollywood" suffix is used to refer to film industries of different languages and countries.

That explains why you never heard of "Hong Kong-wood". It doesn't follow the "-ollywood" format.